wsl fails to obtain permissions except root to access a newly prepared drive
I have purchased a NVMe SSD and installed it onto my desktop. I performed disk initialization and formatting as usual.
But when I try to access the disk from wsl, the difference emerged.

my new drive is volumed as u. When I launch wsl from a folder in it, it is denied.
Unless I have do sudo su, then it will let me access it.
It has created a huge problem for me as I can't use VS code on WSL to edit files, because vs code on WSL can only be launched from a normal user, not the super user.
I have attempted to chmod and chown for the whole drive. It took a long time, but the recycle disk contents cannot be changed. I am still unable to access any contents in U from wsl directly.
How to fix this issue?
